# How do I get section headings to extend into the margin (using the Memoir class)?

Tags: sectioning, margins, memoir

I’m writing a document that uses a rather small text block (`\textwidth`), with the margin holding footnotes, figures and various other material. Because of the narrow text block, section headings frequently span two lines. However, they can often **physically** fit on one line – if they are allowed to extend into the marginal area.

So, how do I get the headings to extend into the margins (while still being broken if they extend too much, i.e., more than `\marginparsep + \marginparwidth`)? I’m using the `Memoir` class.

Here’s a simple example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,article]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{9cm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{1.5em}{5.5cm}{\onelineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter heading}

\section{This heading is too long to fit on one line}

Foo. \marginpar{\lipsum[4]}\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you working one-sided or two-sided? If two-sided, what do you want to do on even pages?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: The document is one-sided, as per my example code. (Well, in my real document I use `twoside` + some magic to make it mostly act like a one-sided document, but that’s not important here.)

Comment: Fastest solution might be to use `xparse` to redefine `\section` and friends (`xparse` makes it easy to still have the extra arguments), and then use this to combine it with `\makebox` construction Gonzalo use in the `titlesec` solution. (untested)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the **memoir** way:

```
\newcommand{\extendedsec}[1]{\noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\Large\bfseries\raggedright#1}}}
\setsecheadstyle{\extendedsec}
```

Change `\textwidth` into what suits you best. I wouldn't fill the whole line.

If you want to fill the whole line, then

```
\newcommand{\extendedsec}[1]{\noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\parbox[t]%
    {\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}%
    {\Large\bfseries\raggedright#1}}}
```

A similar trick is described on page 106 of the manual for **memoir**

Comment: Thanks. I don’t understand why it works (why can `setsecheadstyle` take a command that takes an argument?), but it does extend the heading into the margin (if one replaces `\textwidth` with something larger). However, it also seems to add some space to the **left** of the heading.

Comment: @KarlOveHufthammer Yes, I forgot a `\noindent`

Comment: @egreg OK. Now it’s perfect. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `titlesec` package; in the following example I used a `\parbox` of width `\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep` to format the heading for sections:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,article]{memoir}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{9cm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{1.5em}{5.5cm}{\onelineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}
  {\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth][l]{%
      \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}
{\raggedright\thesection\hspace{1em}#1}}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter heading}

\section{This heading fits now on one single line}

Foo. \marginpar{\lipsum[4]}\lipsum[1]

\section{This heading is too long to fit on one line and will span two lines}

Foo. \marginpar{\lipsum[4]}\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Karl: Note the use of the `explicit` package option to [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). It allows you to "grab hold of" the sectional title by means of the argument `#1` do with it what you want, as in @Gonzalo's answer.

Comment: Thanks. Although this does seem to work, the `titlesec` documentation explicitly says that it’s not compatible with the ‘Memoir’ class, so I’m worried there may be some hidden issues with this solution.

Comment: do consider making the multi-line headings ragged right to avoid uneven spacing.

Comment: @barbara beeton: done.