# Make chapters span into margin in KOMA

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

KOMA-Script allows many customizations, but I do not know where to start to add some extra horizontal space (via `addmargin`) to a chapter's head. It is similar to the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32809/how-do-i-get-section-headings-to-extend-into-the-margin-using-the-memoir-class), but this refers to `memoir`.

Basically I want the chapter title use the whole available width (`\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth`) and not to be typeset like in the following picture. How can I achieve this (best in a KOMA way)?

[image: chapterexample]

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=49.4mm,%
    textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip,asymmetric]{geometry}%
\usepackage{showframe} % for demonstration

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test with a very very very long title}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\chapterlinesformat`:

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=24.8mm,top=27.4mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=107mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=49.4mm,%
    textheight=49\baselineskip,headheight=\baselineskip,asymmetric]{geometry}%
\usepackage{showframe} % for demonstration
\usepackage{lipsum}% for demonstration
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth][l]{% avoid overfull \hbox
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}{% use more width
      \raggedchapter
      \@hangfrom{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Test with a very very very long title}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter into the margin]