# Memoir hangnum chapter style extended into margin

Tags: margins, memoir

I'm trying to extend my chapter heading into the right margin. In the memoir manual an example of this is given for the companion chapter style using the `adjustwidth` environment.

I tried using that to adapt the hangnum chapter style, but now the chapter name is printed below the chapter number (on a new line). How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlrmargins{*}{*}{2.5}
\checkandfixthelayout

\chapterstyle{hangnum}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-5cm}
        \raggedright \chaptitlefont #1\par\nobreak
    \end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Very long title i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32809/how-do-i-get-section-headings-to-extend-into-the-margin-using-the-memoir-class), which works in this MWE, but when I try to implement it I still get into trouble. My chapter titles are colored, and when I add '\color{blue}' the problem returns. Any ideas?

Comment: Found it. I should have used '\textcolor'. This works: '\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\parbox[t]{1.4\textwidth}{\raggedright\chaptitlefont\textcolor{blue}{#1}\par\nobreak}}}'

Comment: Would you like to turn your last comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers the original question ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32809/how-do-i-get-section-headings-to-extend-into-the-margin-using-the-memoir-class)):

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\parb‌​ox[t]{1.4\textwidth}‌​{%
        \raggedright\chapti‌​tlefont#1\par\nobreak}‌​
    }
}
```

To make the color of the title blue use `\textcolor{blue}{#1}` like this:

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\parb‌​ox[t]{1.4\textwidth}‌​{%
        \raggedright\chapti‌​tlefont\textcolor{blue}{#1}\par\nobreak}‌​
    }
}
```