# How do I get headers and footers to extend into the margin (using the Memoir class)?

Tags: formatting, header-footer, margins, memoir, marginnote

Similar to what was asked in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32809/how-do-i-get-section-headings-to-extend-into-the-margin-using-the-memoir-class) I’m writing a document that uses a small text block, with the margin holding some notes. I did not explicitly changed the `\textwidth` directly, only the margins and the `marginparwidth` through the geometry package. Because of the narrow text block, the headers narrow in the same proportion.

So, how do I get the header to extend into the margins `\marginparsep` + `\marginparwidth`? Also... same problem with the page numbers on every chapter's first page, they are not centered and I'd like them to be.

I’m using the Memoir class.

I've been using LaTeX through Overleaf for about 6 months now, so I'm still new. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[
    letterpaper,
    marginparwidth=1.5in,
    right=2in,
    left=1in,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in
]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Artículo~\thesection}{1em}{}

\counterwithout*{footnote}{chapter}
\counterwithout*{section}{chapter}

\usepackage{GoudyIn}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\GoudyInfamily{}}
{\LettrineTextFont{\itshape}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{5}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{1pt}}

\newlist{apartados}{enumerate}{3}
    \setlist[apartados, 1]
    {label=\textbf{\Alph{apartadosi}.}
    }
    \setlist[apartados, 2]
    {label=\textbf{\Roman{apartadosii}.}
    }

\newlist{fracciones}{enumerate}{3}
    \setlist[fracciones, 1]
    {label=\textbf{\Roman{apartadosi}.}
    }
    
\title{TITLE}
\author{Me}
\date{September 2022}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\maketitle

\mainmatter

\part*{PART ONE}

\chapter[A not so long Chapter Title]{A very very very very long Chapter Title
}

\section{}

\marginnote{
    \emph{\footnotesize In this page you can see how the page number at the bottom is not centered}
    }
\noindent\blindtext \footnote{
    \blindtext
    }

\blindtext

\marginnote{
    \emph{\footnotesize In this page you can see how the header (and the page number specifically) is not the full width, including the margin width}
    }
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you extend your code fragment into a small example we can compile please? Just the preamble alone is likely not sufficient to be able to help

Comment: You can do it by modifying the pagestyle (hea;dings),  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694149/page-number-alignment-when-using-marginnote/694203?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#694203

Comment: You a have a look at the code for or the companion pagestyle